# После перебора массива не выводится текст

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть такой код:

HTML

```
<p id="sort" onmouseover="sort(this)">Some text</p>
```

JS

```
var element = document.getElementById("sort");
var text = element.textContent;

var chinese = "甸町画甽甾甿畁畂畃畑";
chinese = chinese.split("");

function sort(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < chinese.length; j++) {
            elem.textContent[i] = chinese[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Суть кода в том, чтобы при наведении мышью он брал один символ из абзаца, и выводил вместо него десять других(поочерёдно) из заданного массива, после чего ставил обратно изначальный символ, и так делал с каждым символом из абзаца.
Пример работы:
Some text
甸ome text
S甸me text
So甸e text
...
Some tex甸
Some text
Но проблема заключается в том, что он ничего не выводит.(Ошибок тоже)

Comment: Описание, код и "пример работы" не соответствуют друг другу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const chinese = "甸町画甽甾甿畁畂畃畑".split("");
const element = document.getElementById('text');
const textElement = element.textContent.split("");


for (i=0; i <= chinese.length; i++ ){
if(textElement[i] === " ") continue;
(function(i){
 setTimeout(function() {
  let char = textElement[i];
   if( i !== textElement.length){
  textElement[i] = chinese[0];
     }
  let newText = textElement.join("");
  textElement[i] = char;
  element.innerHTML = newText;
    }, 1000 * i);
})(i)
 }
```

```html
<p id='text'>Some text</p>
```